Light doesn't show in viewport
I followed a YouTube tutorial and now have problem with lighting.
I can't see it on my model. Dimension on Z axis is 0.75, so model isn't big. I've tried to increase intensity, it didn't help.
Nodes in shading:

Without light

With light


To see your lights while in Material Preview mode, you need to tick the Scene Lights checkbox. Otherwise, while in Material Preview mode, they will have no effect.


Thanks a lot!:)

No problem! I often forget to toggle that too. :)
